# Charts for web application

Tags: java, charts

Does anyone know any good chart api for a web application in java? This question might be asked earlier. What I am looking for , where I can offer different chart options to user for reports and then they can use any chart they want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [amcharts](http://www.amcharts.com/)

it's good, but not free and uses Flash.

### [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

is free.

### [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Answer (score 2):

The google charts API is quite good (more info [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/"here").)
Also [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/"JFreeChart") if you'd rather do it on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Google API looks great, but what about SSL warnings? If my users are running SSL against my servers, then fetching an image from `http(s)://chart.apis.google.com...` will generate an SSL warning, which looks unprofessional.

Is there any way to come around that? One way I could imagine would be to fetch the image serverside, and the stream it out to the browser. The browser would have an image tag like:

```
<img src="myownserver.com/chart?somedescriptive=parameters.../>
```

And when getting this request on my server I would generate a call to Googles API, get the image, and then stream it out, as if was my own file.

But are there any other way to avoid SSL warnings?